# The probability of scoring a penalty is twice the probability of missing it. Total 5 penalties are taken, then the probability of scoring 3 out of 5?

Tags: probability

What I Did:

3 scoring penalties among 5 can be chosen in
        `5c3`
 ways ! After this I'm confused on how to proceed !!

Comment: [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=5$ and $p=\frac23$. Find $P(X=3)$ if it comes to *exactly* $3$ out of $5$ and $P(X\geq3)$ by *at least* $3$ out of $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(\text{scoring})=2P(\text{missing})$ and $P(\text{scoring})+P(\text{missing})=1$, therefore $P(\text{scoring})=2/3$ and $P(\text{missing})=1/3$.

It's Binomial Probability. Your answer is $\binom{5}{3}(2/3)^3(1/3)^2$, or in your notation $(5c3)(2/3)^3(1/3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let's call the probability of success $p$, and failure $q$, then they tell us that 
$$p = 2q.$$
Moreover, it has to be true that 
$$p+q = 1$$
because you either miss or score the penalty.

Then $q = \frac{1}{3}$ and $p = \frac{2}{3}$. Your hunch was right, this is a binomial distribution, and so the probability of scoring *exactly* three is
$$\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 =0.3292181.$$

Comment: how did I miss that !! :p Thanks :)

Comment: @sanA No problem. It happens.